# How to get the parent and only the first child of a related table

Tags: .net, sql, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have this 3 tables:

Process, Action and Process_Actions (Many to Many, which register all **Actions** that a **Process** can execute. Basically, this table have Process_Id, Action_Id and a unique ID (for ordering).

What I want is a LINQ query to get a list of all **Process** and get only the last **Action** (ordered by date)

this is my working SQL query:

```
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, PA.Action_Id FROM Process P
    JOIN Process_Actions PA ON P.Id = PA.Process_Id 
    WHERE PA.Id IN (SELECT MAX (PA.Id) FROM Process_Actions INNER JOIN Process_Actions PA ON P.Id = PA.Process_Id)
```

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see the Action reference in your T-SQL sample.

Comment: I Just need the Action_Id, referenced in Process_Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
context.Processes.Select(p => new { Process = p,
    LastAction = p.Actions.OrderbyDescending(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault() } )
```

Assuming that `Action` has a property`Date` (as you say *ordered by date*).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this

```
var maxId = (from pa in context.Process_Actions 
join pa on pa.Id = pa.Process_Id)
select (int?)pa.Id).Max();

var query = from p in context.Process
join pa in context.Process_Actions on p.Id equals pa.Process_Id
where maxId.Contains(pa.Id)
select new
{
    p.Id, 
    p.Name, 
    pa.Action_Id
}
```